# Restoring Raid 5 Meta data / Table

Tags: raid, raid-5, array

2 part question at end of this text

My problem:
My CMOS was cleared, BIOS was set to IDE instead of RAID.
My understanding (from other sites) is that motherboard Intel ICH10R data is stored in BIOS and/or meta data on the RAID hard drives.

My problem is that I set my BIOS back to RAID and now it shows 4 non-member drives and 2 member drives.  The data should still be intact as the drives are completely functional.

However, my exhaustive research efforts have only turned up the possibility of restoring this so called 'meta' data by using a partition recovery program like ReclaiMe RAID Recovery.

My problem however, is that in order to recover this 'meta' or partition table I need to know which drives were in the RAID array.  I had 6 drives but I had 2 different Arrays.  Therefore, I have no clue as to which ports belong to which of the two arrays.

My question:
1) Most important question.  Is there some software tool that can be used to find out which drives belong to which array?

According to my research I only need to change all disk to non-member disk, then recreate the RAID with the SAME EXACT drives (which leads to question 1) and same strip size.

Possible 3rd step may require using ReclaMe RAID Recovery to restore the meta data as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that ReclaiMe RAID recovery (freeware) will test 2 or more drives, and after scanning will indicate if those 2 or more drives belong together, in my case I found the first 2 then started testing and found a match for the 3rd

At this point though I still need to actually figure out how to recover the metadata or the data from the drives